# Grails / Jackson JSON Serialization How To

Tags: json, grails, serialization, jackson

How do I 'enable' Jackson Serialization in a Grails application?

In BuildConfig.groovy I added:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
```

Is that all that is required?  Or is some other magic in Config.groovy needed?

How to serialize a property with only a getter?

I want to include in the generated JSON the value from a 'get' method in one of the Domain Classes.  I tried variations of this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(setterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
class SportsAgent {
    String name
    String address
    String phone
    String email
    String state

    Client client

    @JsonProperty('clientName')
    String getClientName() {
        if (client) {
            client.name
        }
    }
}
```

This does serialize to JSON, but does NOT include 'clientName'.  All the other variants I tried usually gave some parsing error.   I have done this successfully in older versions of Jackson in Java with @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize, but those annotations are not there now.